# Install Mogli Gem on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to install the mogli gem( http://github.com/mmangino/mogli ) on rails 3 and am running into problems with the configuration.  I have **NO** prior experience with Rails 2.

For Rails 2

```
Add config.gem "mogli" to environment.rb
```

For Rails 3, I added the following to the gemfile.

```
gem 'mogli'
```

For Rails 2, routes

```
map.resource :oauth, :controller=>"oauth"
map.root :controller=>"oauth"
map.oauth_callback "/oauth/create", :controller=>"oauth", :action=>"create"
```

For Rails 3, I added

```
resources :oauth
root :to => "oauth#index"
```

And I do not know how to represent the **map.oauth_callback** in Rails 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
match "/oauth/create", :to => "oauth#create", :via => "get", :as => "oauth_callback"
```

Comment: [this](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) article is pretty good for helping with routes problems

Comment: PS - beware that the original route, is a singular resource `map.resource :oauth, :controller=>"oauth"` - you have specified a plural i.e. `resources :oauth` - might be better to change it to `resource :oauth` - just bear it in mind - hope this helps

Comment: @Dara I have my resource set as singular and my controller named as singular and it works fine.